# What is "Green TX" in WiFi (Atheros AR5B97 adapter for laptop)

Tags: windows-7, windows, wireless-networking, wifi-driver, properties

In the device options I am trying to get the most out of my card but I am wondering what Green TX (on/off) is? I can't find it on google.

So, what does Green TX mean and what is it for, what does it affect?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't really find an 'official' source for it, but its probably a low power transmission(TX) mode for the adaptor. It will lower power use (yay!) but reduce signal strength. Turn it on if you want power saving and are nearer to your AP (so the lower transmission power will be less of an issue). I'd personally leave it as is.

Answer (score 4):

Google for "atheros wi-fi green transmission mode". From [here](http://www.tmcnet.com/wifirevolution/articles/131487-atheros-launches-wi-fi-bluetooth-solutions.htm):

*Atheros' new products also use a Green Transmission mode, which dynamically adjusts the system's Wi-Fi transmit power depending on the distance between the router and the client device.*